# How to target background pane in tmux

Tags: tmux

In a tmux window, let's say I have 3 panes, indices 0, 1 and 2.

If I choose pane `2` to be the active pane, and then do `break-pane -d`, it will send that pane to the background.

In order to recall that pane back, I'd do `join-pane -s $.0`. Even though the hidden pane doesn't have the index `0`, for some reason `$.0` works. I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere for what this means. The tmux manpage seems to suggest that the `src-pane` can be a pane ID, but no reference to how to target the pane in the background.

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no background, there's no "hidden".

> `break-pane -d`, it will send that pane to the background.

Not to the background but to a *new window*. A new window gets created.

> Even though the hidden pane doesn't have the index `0`, for some reason `$.0` works.

The pane does have the index `0` *in the new window*. This `0` is the pane index, relative to the window. It is different than `%0`, which is a unique pane ID and may belong to a different pane.

`$` specifies a window. It's a token for a window with the highest number. It may be the new window created with `break-pane` or *it may not*: `break-pane` creates a window with the lowest possible number, so if the already existing windows have a gap in numbering then `$` after `break-pane` will not refer to the window you want.

---

A firm way to identify the pane is to get its pane ID from `$TMUX_PANE` or `tmux display-message -pF "#{pane_id}"`; or at least to get the information about the new window when invoking `break-pane`:

```
tmux break-pane -dP
```

You can store any of these in a shell variable, but it makes little sense to store it in a shell in the pane that is being moved. If you lose track of the pane then you won't be able to locate the shell with the variable. So it's better to use another shell and specify the target pane with `-s` when you `break-pane`. Note if you decide to provide a pane ID to `break-pane -s` then it's better to store the ID in the first place rather than what `break-pane -P` returns.

---

Fortunately `break-pane` allows you to *name* the new window:

```
tmux break-pane -d -n background
```

*Then* you can say you have sent the pane to the `background` :) To get the pane back:

```
tmux join-pane -s background
```

(assuming you haven't messed with the new window since `break-pane`, otherwise `background`, which identifies a *window*, may not be enough to identify the right *pane*).

---

> I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere for what this means.

All what I wrote I had got from `man 1 tmux` (although I admit the documentation is huge and it may seem overwhelming in the beginning).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is fantastic. One quick question: when doing `join-pane`, just `background` is enough to identify the pane in the new window? Also, after `join-pane`, will the `background` window be cleaned up?

Comment: @TriNguyen (1) It's true `background` identifies the window, not a pane. When tmux expects a pane and you specify a window, there's a rule to choose a pane from that window: if the pane index is omitted, the currently active pane in the specified window is used. (2) If no pane remains in a window, the window is destroyed. You can confirm this with `tmux list-windows`.